# Disable images in Selenium Python with chromedriver

Tags: python, image, selenium, load

I would like to speed up the loading of selenium python pages. I have found several codes, but the problem is that it only loads me one right main window, and then the next ones where the images load. What is the best code? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read what's on-topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preference are not supported in headless mode so a universal method would be to add arguments :

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&safe=off&hl=en&gl=ar&tbm=isch&sxsrf=ALeKk02lEcMPPT8VE72p7l8mkzkQmdAtqA%3A1615809915268&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=937&ei=e01PYPuIDszDgQa76aHIBQ&q=stackoverflow+meme&oq=stackov&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAxgAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADoECCMQJzoICAAQsQMQgwE6BQgAELEDULcRWMYaYLcjaABwAHgAgAFGiAHoApIBATeYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZw&sclient=img")
   
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjL7MOCobLvAhVUweYKHYNYC3oQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=stackoverflow+&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECCMQJzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzICCAAyAggAMgIIADIECAAQQzICCAAyAggAMgIIAFDtvQFY7b0BYIq_AWgAcAB4AIABPogBPpIBATGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=gE1PYMusCtSCmweDsa3QBw&bih=937&biw=1920&gl=ar&safe=off&hl=en")
```

This will disable all the images

Comment: Thanks! but do I have to add arguments for each open tab or window?

Comment: No it should work for all tabs as the chrome instance is opened with that settings

Comment: i have this error: chrome_options.add_arguments('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
NameError: name 'chrome_options' is not defined...

I used Chromedriver

Comment: Thanks but not work :(

error:
   chrome_options.add_arguments('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'add_arguments'

Comment: chrome_options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')

Comment: Perfect :) Instead the advertisements or banners still appear. it's normal?

Comment: can you give the link so that i can try it out

Comment: look I tried, but it opens a new window with the images disabled, but they are not valid for the new windows that I open later with the command "driver.get ('example website)"

Comment: @lolino see the upodated answer it works fine

Comment: you might be reinitializing driver object somewhere

Answer (score 1):

You can do it including this code in your script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Thanks Fabix! But  I add it at the beginning of the script?  and does it work for all the tabs and windows that I will open next?

Comment: use options instead of chrome_options (chrome_options is depreciated)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable all then do

```
            options.add_experimental_option(
                "prefs", {
                    "profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2,
                    "profile.managed_default_content_settings.stylesheet": 2,
                    "profile.managed_default_content_settings.fonts": 2,
                }
            )
```